# 3 div uno abajo del otro con contenido que se superpone

Tags: html, css, div

Tengo que tener 3 divs, los cuales denominaré personalInfo_header, personalInfo_contenedor_central y personalInfo-footer. Los cuales los 3 están contenidos en un div con id main-container.

El inconveniente que tengo es que si tengo contenido en el div personalInfo_contenedor_central, este muchas veces sobrepasa su lugar y superpone al contenido de abajo, del div personalInfo-footer. **¿Cómo es posible solucionar esto?**

El siguiente es el código HTML:

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="personalInfo_header">
    </div>
    <div id="personalInfo_contenedor_central">
    </div>
    <div id="personalInfo-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el código css.

```
#main-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
  }

#personalInfo_header{
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
  
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    
    justify-content: flex-start;
  
    border:solid;
    border-color: green;
  }

#personalInfo_contenedor_central {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
  
    position:relative;
    top:15%;   
      
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    border:solid;
    border-color: blue;
  
}

#personalInfo-footer{
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;

    position:fixed;
    top:75%;   
          
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    border:solid;
    border-color: red;
  }
```

El problema es que tengo un formulario en personalInfo_contenedor_central que obtiene datos por un API REST y este es variable.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que uno se coloque abajo del otro independientemente del tamaño que ocupen los divs. Porque el tamaño es variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
#personalInfo_contenedor_central {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
```

*Como la altura la tenias en %50 supongo por razones de estilo, lo que puedes hacer es un margen o un padding...